# Can't use MacBook after updating with broken screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

My screen is totally broken and displays full black. I was using my MacBook Pro 2019 using an external screen. After an update, using the external screen no longer works. I have tried in many external screens. How can solve my problem? Is there a solution except buying new screen?

After starting MacBook I close the lid and Apple logo screen comes up, but when it is finished the screen is again black.

How can I use it by totally removing the display?

Comment: Perhaps there is a software issue if your Mac turns black AFTER booting. As a first step perhaps try if you can boot into recovery mode (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl338cf9a8/mac). It might also make it easier for other people to answer your question if you add some information to your question (which model MacBook, version of macOS, peripherals).

Comment: Did you try command-f1 (use fn to activate function keys) ?